# Problem with proxy property in package.json (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've added the proxy property in package.json that is pointing to http://localhost:8080/ becouse I want to connect my node.js backend with my react frontend. However after setting this, my react app starts on the port 8080 or on whatever port I set in the proxy in package.json. What I'm doing wrong? I would like to start my react app on port 3000 and leave the port 8080 free for the node backend.

Here is my whole package.json file:

```
   {
  "name": "restaurants-portfolio-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev:server": "nodemon ./backend/server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
}
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? Could you please include your code sample here?

Comment: @konekoya yes I'm using the create-react-app. I've edited the question and pasted the code from my package.json file.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make it clear. Could you put together a fully reproducible sample. Like a Repo or something like codesanbox.io or codepen.io

Comment: @konekoya so here is my github repo: https://github.com/bartekw2213/RestaurantFinder

Comment: @konekoya already solved the issue, the reason was the .env file that I made to specify the port for the node backend but the react front-end also used it, silly mistake but thank you